# Flutter error '_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>')' on JSON nested array

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I have a json nested array to display on my apps, but i encounter with error as the title question. Here is my code on the controller

```
Future<List<staredTender>> staredTenderCon() async {
  final Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  final SharedPreferences? prefs = await _prefs;
  final token = prefs?.get('jwttoken');
  final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
          ApiEndPoints.baseUrl + ApiEndPoints.otherEndPoints.staredTender),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
      });

  List<staredTender> staredTenderlist = [];

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var urjson = json.decode(response.body);

    for (var jsondata in urjson) {
      staredTenderlist.add(staredTender.fromJson(jsondata));
    }
    //return staredTender.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    return urjson.map((e) => staredTender.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }
  return staredTenderlist;
}
```

The error occured on:
var urjson = json.decode(response.body);
for (var jsondata in urjson)

If im right, this error occured because the json.body return map, but my code require it to return in Iterable. Other than that, i have no idea where it is wrong

Here is my json file:

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "reason": "successful",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "639015d840ca7d1b39017b3f",
            "admin_id": 29169,
            "agency_name": "KEMENTERIAN KESIHATAN",
            "agency_type": {
                "id": 842,
                "term": "Government"
            },
            "attachment": [
                {
                    "filename": "QT220000000039366.zip",
                    "ext": ".zip",
                    "filesize": "444 KB",
                    "url": "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/tenderdb2/QT220000000039366.zip"
                },
                {
                    "filename": "QT220000000039366.png",
                    "ext": ".png",
                    "filesize": "73 KB",
                    "url": "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/tenderdb2/QT220000000039366.png"
                }
            ],
            "available_at": "",
            "briefing_date": "",
            "briefing_venue": "",
            "cidb": [],
            "cidb_grade": [],
            "cidb_grade_serial": [],
            "cidb_serial": [],
            "closing_date": 1671019200,
            "collection_address": "",
            "contact_person": [
                "MOHD HADI BIN MOHD ZIN"
            ],
            "description": "PERKHIDMATAN PENYELENGGARAAN SISTEM PENGURUSAN INTEGRASI KAWALAN EFEKTIF SUBSTAN (SPIKES) SEDIA ADA DI PROGRAM PERKHIDMATAN FARMASI, KEMENTERIAN KESIHATAN MALAYSIA, QT220000000039366, IBU PEJABAT KEMENTERIAN BAHAGIAN PERKHIDMATAN FARMASI PEJABAT AM | MOHD HADI BIN MOHD ZIN MHADI@MOH.GOV.MY 78413239 |",
            "developer": "RidhZ",
            "document_cost": "",
            "document_title": "SEBUT HARGA - IBU PEJABAT KEMENTERIAN BAHAGIAN PERKHIDMATAN FARMASI PEJABAT AM - QT220000000039366 - PERKHIDMATAN PENYELENGGARAAN SISTEM PENGURUSAN INTEGRASI KAWALAN EFEKTIF SUBSTAN (SPIKES) SEDIA ADA DI PROGRAM PERKHIDMATAN FARMASI, KEMENTERIAN KESIHATAN MALAYSIA",
            "email_address": [
                "mhadi@moh.gov.my"
            ],
            "fax_no": [
                ""
            ],
            "from": "ep-creepy-crawler",
            "last_collection_date": 1671019200,
            "mid_id": "b1eb1400be929e47f28e3b2f8694b927",
            "mof": [
                {
                    "term_id": 602,
                    "term": "Software – Supply all computer software, operating system, database, off-the- Shelf packages including maintenance",
                    "slug": "ep-21-01-03"
                }
            ],
            "mof_serial": [
                602
            ],
            "no": "",
            "no_tender": "QT220000000039366",
            "opening_date": 1670414400,
            "payable_to": "",
            "payment_method": [],
            "payment_method_serial": [],
            "project_value": "",
            "publish_unixtime": 1670414400,
            "site_venue": "",
            "site_visit_date": "",
            "slug": "sebut-harga-tender-ibu-pejabat-kementerian-bahagian-perkhidmatan-farmasi-pejabat-am-qt220000000039366-perkhidmatan-penyelenggaraan-sistem-pengurusan-integrasi-kawalan-efektif-substan-spikes-sedia-ada-di-program-perkhidmatan-farmasi-kementerian-kesihatan-malaysia",
            "source": {
                "id": 841,
                "term": "Internet"
            },
            "source_description": "https://www.eperolehan.gov.my/quotation-tender-notice",
            "states": [
                {
                    "term_id": 26,
                    "term": "Selangor",
                    "slug": "selangor"
                },
                {
                    "term_id": 28,
                    "term": "Kuala Lumpur",
                    "slug": "kuala-lumpur"
                },
                {
                    "term_id": 23,
                    "term": "Putrajaya",
                    "slug": "putrajaya"
                }
            ],
            "states_serial": [
                26,
                28,
                23
            ],
            "status": "1",
            "tel_no": [
                "78413239"
            ],
            "tender_type": {
                "term_id": 844,
                "term": "Open",
                "slug": "open"
            },
            "unixtime": 1670387160,
            "document_type": "sebut-harga"
        },
```

Comment: You are assigning the wrong data to an array. Try with this 

staredTenderlist = staredTender.fromJson(jsondata["data"]);

Comment: @ChiragSondagar where should i change the code line?

Comment: Remove for loop and add this

staredTenderlist = staredTender.fromJson(jsondata["data"]);